# Authorization failed when uploading to Google Group

Tags: google-groups, google-groups-api

I am trying to upload a message to a Google Group using this http call:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/upload/groups/v1/groups/mygroupname@domain.com/archive?ploadType=media&access_token=XYZ...
```

(Of course substituting the correct email address for the group, and the actual token). This produces the http error 401 (Authorization failed).  The target account is Google Workspace.  I am using a service account that has the Google Groups API enabled. I have added this scope to the service account and authorized it for my domain:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/apps.groups.migration
```

As a test to make sure I have that scope authorized, I take the token that was generated and run it through this API:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=XYZ...
```

The json returned does have the apps.groups.migration scope (along with others for mail, calendar, etc.).  I have no trouble accessing those other data types.

Any idea what I could be missing here?

Comment: Running into this same issue.  Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: That problem seems to have gone away.  I believe that the Google Groups API will only work with a service account - can't remember what I was using when I posted this, but it works now.  I did run into an issue, getting http 400 (unable to parse) on the upload.  Turns out, Google requires a Message-ID header in the RFC-822 message.

Comment: Hm, thanks for the info.  Are you a domain admin for your domain?  I'm trying to import to a group that I own, but I am not a domain admin.  I suspect this may be the reason I'm getting 401s.

Comment: I do need to specify the administrator's email when I obtain the auth token, otherwise I do get the http 401 as you reported.  As I mentioned, we use a service account that gives us access to all user's data.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  That answers my question.  I was trying to use either my own account or a service account I created, but no dice.  I did ask my domain admin for a service account for the purposes of importing an archive, but they refused.  So I guess in my particular case, I'm SOL.  Weird to me that I can't import an archive to a list where I have the Owner role, but there's not much I can do about that except complain.